# Inequality on Root of Polynomials

Tags: inequality, polynomials

Suppose that $|a_i|<1$ for $i\in \{1,2,3,4\}$, and consider the polynomials

$$  x^2 - (a_1+a_2+a_3)x + a_1 a_2 + a_1 a_3 + a_2 a_3  - 1,$$

and

$$ x^2 - (a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4)x + a_1 a_2 + a_1 a_3 + a_1 a_4 + a_2 a_3+ a_2 a_4+ a_3 a_4 - a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4  - 1.$$

> I want to show that, in both cases, any real root $x^*$ of these polynomials must satisfy $|x^*|<2$.

---

Though it may look like it, this is not a homework question. It is something that appeared in my own research. It looks simple, but I've tried the usual avenues without luck. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f,g$ be given by
\begin{align*}
f(x)&=x^2-(a_1+a_2+a_3)x + a_1a_2+a_1a_3+a_2a_3 -1\\[4pt]
g(x)&=x^2-(a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4)x+a_1a_2+a_1a_3+a_1a_4+a_2a_3+a_2a_4+ a_3 a_4 - a_1a_2a_3a_4 - 1\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
where $|a_i|<1$ for $i\in \{1,2,3,4\}$.

The goal is to show that any real root $r$ of either $f$ or $g$ satisfies $|r| < 2$.

First consider $f$ . . .

As noted in David's answer, the vertex of the parabola $y=f(x)$ has $x$-coordinate
$$\frac{a_1+a_2+a_3}{2}$$
which lies in the interval $\left(-\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2}\right)$.

Hence to show that any real root $r$ of $f$ satisfies $|r| < 2$, it suffices to show that $f(-2) > 0$ and $f(2) > 0$.

For $f(-2)$, we have the identity
\begin{align*}
f(-2)&=3+2(a_1+a_2+a_3)+a_1a_2+a_2a_3+a_3a_1\\[4pt]
&=(1+a_1)(1+a_2)+(1+a_2)(1+a_3)+(1+a_3)(1+a_1)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
hence $f(-2) > 0$.

Similarly, for $f(2)$, we have the identity
\begin{align*}
f(2)&=3-2(a_1+a_2+a_3)+a_1a_2+a_2a_3+a_3a_1\\[4pt]
&=(1-a_1)(1-a_2)+(1-a_2)(1-a_3)+(1-a_3)(1-a_1)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
hence $f(2) > 0$.

This completes the analysis for $f$.

Next consider $g$ . . .

Note that the vertex of the parabola $y=g(x)$ has $x$-coordinate
$$\frac{a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4}{2}$$
which lies in the interval $(-2,2)$.

Hence to show that any real root $r$ of $g$ satisfies $|r| < 2$, it suffices to show that $g(-2) > 0$ and $g(2) > 0$.

For $g(-2)$, we have the identity
$$
g(-2)
=
3
+
2(a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4)
+
a_1a_2+a_1a_3+a_1a_4+a_2a_3+a_2a_4+a_3a_4
-
a_1a_2a_3a_4
$$
which is our target for the $\text{LHS}$ of the chain below . . .
\begin{align*}
&1-a_1a_2 > 0\\[4pt]
\implies\;&(1-a_1a_2)a_3 > (1-a_1a_2)(-1)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&a_3-a_1a_2a_3 > -1+a_1a_2\\[4pt]
\implies\;&(2+a_1+a_2)+(a_3-a_1a_2a_3) > (2+a_1+a_2)+(-1+a_1a_2)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&2+a_1+a_2+a_3-a_1a_2a_3 > 1+a_1+a_2+a_1a_2\\[4pt]
\implies\;&2+a_1+a_2+a_3-a_1a_2a_3 > (1+a_1)(1+a_2)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&2+a_1+a_2+a_3-a_1a_2a_3 > 0\\[4pt]
\implies\;&(2+a_1+a_2+a_3-a_1a_2a_3)a_4 > (2+a_1+a_2+a_3-a_1a_2a_3)(-1)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&2a_4+a_1a_4+a_2a_4+a_3a_4-a_1a_2a_3a_4 > -2
-a_1-a_2-a_3
+a_1a_2a_3
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&(3+2a_1+2a_2+2a_3+a_1a_2+a_1a_3+a_2a_3)+(2a_4+a_1a_4+a_2a_4+a_3a_4-a_1a_2a_3a_4)\\[4pt]
&> \\[4pt]
&(3+2a_1+2a_2+2a_3+a_1a_2+a_1a_3+a_2a_3)+(-2-a_1-a_2-a_3+a_1a_2a_3)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
3
+
2(a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4)
+
a_1a_2+a_1a_3+a_1a_4+a_2a_3+a_2a_4+a_3a_4
-
a_1a_2a_3a_4
\\[4pt]
&> \\[4pt]
&1
+
a_1+a_2+a_3
+
a_1a_2+a_2a_3+a_3a_1
+
a_1a_2a_3
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&g(-2) > (1+a_1)(1+a_2)(1+a_3)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&g(-2) > 0\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Similarly, for $g(2)$, we have the identity
$$
g(2)
=
3
-
2(a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4)
+
a_1a_2+a_1a_3+a_1a_4+a_2a_3+a_2a_4+a_3a_4
-
a_1a_2a_3a_4
$$
which is our target for the $\text{LHS}$ of the chain below . . .
\begin{align*}
&1-a_1a_2 > 0\\[4pt]
\implies\;&(1-a_1a_2)a_3 < (1-a_1a_2)(1)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&a_3-a_1a_2a_3 < 1-a_1a_2\\[4pt]
\implies\;&(-2+a_1+a_2)+(a_3-a_1a_2a_3) < (-2+a_1+a_2)+(1-a_1a_2)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&-2+a_1+a_2+a_3-a_1a_2a_3 < -1+a_1+a_2-a_1a_2\\[4pt]
\implies\;&-2+a_1+a_2+a_3-a_1a_2a_3 < -(1-a_1)(1-a_2)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&-2+a_1+a_2+a_3-a_1a_2a_3 < 0\\[4pt]
\implies\;&(-2+a_1+a_2+a_3-a_1a_2a_3)a_4 > (-2+a_1+a_2+a_3-a_1a_2a_3)(1)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&-2a_4+a_1a_4+a_2a_4+a_3a_4-a_1a_2a_3a_4 > -2
+a_1+a_2+a_3
-a_1a_2a_3
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&(3-2a_1-2a_2-2a_3+a_1a_2+a_1a_3+a_2a_3)+(-2a_4+a_1a_4+a_2a_4+a_3a_4-a_1a_2a_3a_4)\\[4pt]
&> \\[4pt]
&(3-2a_1-2a_2-2a_3+a_1a_2+a_1a_3+a_2a_3)+(-2+a_1+a_2+a_3-a_1a_2a_3)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&
3
-
2(a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4)
+
a_1a_2+a_1a_3+a_1a_4+a_2a_3+a_2a_4+a_3a_4
-
a_1a_2a_3a_4
\\[4pt]
&> \\[4pt]
&1
-a_1-a_2-a_3
+a_1a_2+a_2a_3+a_3a_1
-a_1a_2a_3
\\[4pt]
\implies\;&g(2) > (1-a_1)(1-a_2)(1-a_3)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&g(2) > 0\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

This completes the analysis for $g$.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a partial answer for the first one.  Write
$$f(x)=x^2-(a_1+a_2+a_3)x+a_1a_2+a_1a_3+a_2a_3-1\ ;$$
I shall show that any real root is less than $2$.  The curve $y=f(x)$ is a parabola with vertex at $\frac12(a_1+a_2+a_3)$, which is between $-\frac32$ and $\frac32$; so  $f$ is increasing on $[2,\infty)$, and it suffices to show that $f(2)>0$.  We have
$$f(2)=3-2(a_1+a_2+a_3)+(a_1a_2+a_1a_3+a_2a_3)=g'(1)\ ,$$
where
$$g(x)=x^3-(a_1+a_2+a_3)x^2+(a_1a_2+a_1a_3+a_2a_3)x-a_1a_2a_3\ .$$
But
$$g(x)=(x-a_1)(x-a_2)(x-a_3)$$
is a cubic with positive leading coefficient and all roots in $(-1,1)$; so $g$ is increasing whenever $x>\max(a_1,a_2,a_3)$, and in particular $g'(1)>0$.