# A Surprising Result about a Recurrent Sequence of Functions

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, recurrence-relations

Suppose $\rho\in(0,1)$ and $\tau>0$, and consider the sequence of functions $\{g_0(z),\ldots,g_{n+1}(z)\}$ such that, 
\begin{align}
g_0(z)&= \tau(1-\rho z), \\[1.5ex]
g_{k }\left(  z\right)&  =\frac{1+g_{k-1}\left(  \lambda_{k}\right)
g_{k-1}\left(  z\right)  }{g_{k-1}\left(  \lambda_{k}\right)
-g_{k-1}\left(  z\right)  }\frac{z-\lambda_{k}}{1-\lambda_{k} z}.  
\end{align}
Suppose that $n\ge 2$, $\lambda_{n+1}=0$, and that $\{\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_{n}\}$ satisfy 
\begin{equation}\tag1
 \frac{g_{n+1} (0) g_{n+1}(\lambda_j^{-1}) + 1}{g_{n+1}(0) g_{n+1}(\lambda_i^{-1}) +1}\;\; \frac{g_{0}(\lambda_j) {g
}_{0}(\lambda_j^{-1})+1}{g_{0}(\lambda_i) {g
}_{0}(\lambda_i^{-1})+1} =\frac{g_0(\lambda_j)}{g_0(\lambda_i)}, \;\;\;\text{for } i,j\in \{1,\ldots, n\}.
\end{equation}

> **Conjecture:** $|\lambda_i|>1$ for at least one $i\in\{1,\ldots, n\}$.

---

**Observations:**

Let $x\equiv\rho +\frac{1+\tau^{-2}}{\rho}$ and notice that $x>2$. We have been able to establish the following partial results:

- For $n=2$, equation $(1)$ implies $$x^2-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)x+\lambda_1\lambda_2=1.$$ It follows that $(x-\lambda_1)(x-\lambda_2)=1$, so that it must be that either $|\lambda_1|>1$ or $|\lambda_2|>1$;
- For $n=3$ and $n=4$, equation $(1)$ implies the quadratic equations in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3287373/287326), and the final step of the result is established in the answers to the question;
- For $n= 5$ we have checked the result numerically. We can provide the associated polynomial if someone is interested in it.

One potentially useful property that follows from the definitions is that   $$g_{k}(  z) -g_{k}(\lambda_{k+1})=a_k \frac{z-\lambda_{k+1}}{1-\lambda_{k}z} $$ for some scalar $a_k$ that depends on $\{\rho,\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_{n}\}$.

---

We have been struggling with this problem for a while, but aside from the particular cases listed above, which we obtained by brute force, we haven't been able to make much progress. Any help would be much appreciated.